# Convergence of sine series

Tags: sequences-and-series, partial-differential-equations

I'm reading the book *Heat Transfer* by J.P. Holman. On the chapter of unsteady-state conduction, page 140, the author remarks:

> The final series solution is therefore:
>   $${\theta(x,t) \over \theta_i} = 
> {4\over \pi} \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} {1\over n} e^{-\left({n\pi/L}\right)^2\alpha \,t}\sin{n\pi x \over L}$$
>   We note, of course, that at $t=0$ the series on the right side of the Equation must converge to unity for all values of x.

In this equation $0 < x < L$, and $\alpha$ is a finite constant. My question is, how can I proof that

$${4 \over \pi}\sum^{\infty}_{\substack{n=1}} {1\over n} \sin{n\pi x \over L} = 1$$

Additional information: The solution presented above solves the PDE:
$${\partial^2 \theta(x,t) \over \partial x^2} = {1\over \alpha}{\partial^2 \theta(x,t) \over \partial t^2} $$ with initial and boundary conditions:
\begin{align}
\theta(x,0) &= \theta_i \qquad &0\leq x \leq L\\ 
\theta(0,t) &=0  \qquad & t > 0 \\
\theta(L,t) &=0  \qquad & t > 0
\end{align}

Comment: There is a problem if $x=L$. I don't see how the sum then can become $1$ as you are taking sines of multiples of pi, which is zero

Comment: I edited my question, I had $0\leq x \leq L$ but should be $0 < x <L$.

Comment: Ok, so $x<L$, now let's assume $2x=L$, now the sine term becomes $1$ and $-1$ alternatively (with zero's in between). The series then becomes $1-1/3+1/5-1/7+...$. Is it possible for this sum to become $1$?

Comment: Whether the result holds or not, you should be asking if the last sum is equal to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ for all values of $x\in(0,L)$; not to 1.

Comment: Hmmm... Note that $$-\sum_{n\geqslant1} \frac1ne^{-2in\theta}=\log(1-e^{-2i\theta})=-i\theta+\log(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta})=-i\theta+\log(2i\sin\theta)$$
hence $$\sum \frac1n\sin(2n\theta)=\Im\left(-\sum_{n\geqslant1} \frac1ne^{-2in\theta}\right)=\Im\left(-i\theta+i\frac\pi2+\log(2\sin\theta)\right)=\frac\pi2-\theta$$ for every $\theta$ in $(0,\pi)$, in particular, for every $u$ in $(0,1)$, $$\sum \frac1n\sin(n\pi u)=\frac{\pi-u}2$$

Comment: @Did For what it's worth, I'm not quite sure about the statement in the book itself. Tracking down the actual statement ([here is the corresponding image](http://imgur.com/UHfpgIs)), it looks like the author may be using a very peculiar notation to restrict the summation to odd indices?

Comment: @ClementC. You may well be right, since $$\frac{d}{dz}\sum_{n\geqslant0} \frac{z^{2n+1}}{2n+1}=\sum_{n\geqslant0}z^{2n}=\frac1{1-z^2}=\frac12\left(\frac1{1-z}+\frac1{1+z}\right)$$ hence $$\sum_{n\geqslant0} \frac{z^{2n+1}}{2n+1}=\frac12\log\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)$$
In particular, $$\sum_{n\geqslant0} \frac1{2n+1}\sin(2(2n+1)\theta)=\frac12\Im\log\left(\frac{1+e^{2i\theta}}{1-e^{2i\theta}}\right)=\frac12\Im\log\left(i\cot\theta\right)=\frac\pi4$$ for every $\theta$ in $(0,\frac\pi2)$, to ensure that $\cot\theta>0$. Nice catch, Clément...

Comment: @ClementC. Not so special notation, in fact. It is clearly written there that the sum must be taken over $\;n=1,3,5,...\;$ **odd** ...!

Comment: @DonAntonio Sure, it's written -- but I've never seen that notation anywhere before. Writing $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n,\qquad n=1,3,5,\dots$$ does appear very strange to be -- I've only ever seen $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{2n-1}$$ or $$\sum_{\substack{n\geq 1\\ n \text{ odd}}}^\infty a_{n}$$ for that, i.e. where the restriction on the indices is plainly apparent *in the summation itself*.

Comment: @ClementC. Aren't both notations equally clear? In fact, the one in your link may be clearer and neater when typing.

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't want to judge the notations -- I'm just saying the one used in the book seems less common to me (I had never seen it before), and clearly may be confusing (as the OP definitely missed it).

Answer (score 1):

You have written a wave equation instead of a heat equation. The equation is likely to be
$$
               \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial t}=\alpha\frac{\partial^2\theta}{\partial x^2}, \\
                 \theta(x,0)=\theta_i \\
                 \theta(0,t)=0,\;\; t > 0, \\
                 \theta(L,t)=0,\;\; t > 0.
$$
The separated solutions $\theta(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ must satisfy
\begin{align}
                X''(x)=\lambda X(x), \;\; & \;\; T'(t)=\lambda T(t). \\
                X(0)=0,\; X(L)=0. \;\; &
\end{align}
with the added initial condition $\theta(x,0)=\theta_i$ is a constant function. The solutions of the $X$ equations determine $\lambda_n=n^2\pi^2/L^2$, with corresponding solutions $X_n$ that are constant multiplies of $X_n(x)=\sin(n\pi x/L)$. The corresponding solutions $T_n$ are $T_n(t)=e^{-\alpha n^2\pi^2 t/L^2}$. The general solution is then
$$
             \theta(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n e^{-\alpha n^2\pi^2t/L^2}\sin(n\pi x/L),
$$
where the constants $A_n$ are determined by the initial condition
$$
           \theta_i = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\sin(n\pi x/L)
$$
and the orthgonality conditions $\int_{0}^{L}X_n(x)X_m(x)dx = 0$ for $n\ne m$:
$$
        \theta_i\int_{0}^{L}\sin(n\pi x/L) = A_n\int_{0}^{L}\sin^2(n\pi x/L)dx \\
    \theta_i \frac{L}{n\pi}\{1-\cos(n\pi)\} = A_n \frac{L}{2} \\
         \frac{2}{n\pi}(1-(-1)^n)\theta_i=A_n.
$$
As you noted, there is a problem at $x=0,L$ for $t=0$ and this is due to the conditions imposed. If you want continuity in $t$ at $t=0$ on $[x=0,x-L]$, then the conditions are incompatible because $\theta(x,0)=\theta_i$ at $x=0$ and $x=L$, which is at odds with $\theta(0,t)=0$ for $t > 0$ and $\theta(L,t)=0$ for $t > 0$. So, unless you have a discontinuity in $t$ at $t=0$ at $x=0,L$, then the solution will not match all the required conditions. This is reflected in the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\sin(n\pi x/L)$, which converges to $0$ at $x=0$ and at $x=L$, but converges to $\theta_i$ in $0 < x < L$. The peculiar behavior should mostly be blamed on the conditions for the problem, which require a discontinuity in $t$ at $t=0$ for the enpoints $x=0$ and $x=L$.

The solution given in the problem is incorrect. And you cannot prove the identity you want because the sin series of the constant function is unique, and I have given the correct one. And, that series I have given will converge to $\theta_i$ on $(0,L)$, but of course converges to $0$ at $0,L$.

Comment: Read the comments -- the key is that the summation is over odd indices, $$\sum_{n \text{ odd}}$$not $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty.$$ Your answer is not addressing the question/issue at all.

Comment: @ClementC : There is only one Fourier sine series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\sin(n\pi x/L)$ converging to the constant $\theta_i$ on $(0,L)$. And I have given it. How does that not address the issue?

Comment: Because the question is explicit "how do I prove *this equality*, and *this equality* is wrong. You basically explain how one would go to solve the original, initial question from the book, but the question is about a particular step in the proof, in that book.

Comment: @ClementC : My solution is the correct one, and it is unique among such solutions. So, the book is wrong. Mine not only addresses the issue, but it shows the correct method to solve the equation. So I've gone above and beyond.

Comment: *But you do not answer the OP's question* -- have you read it? Any answer would have to address the specific question, starting maybe by "you cannot prove what you ask, as what you stated is incorrect." The question is not how to solve the PDE: it's why the identity from the book (incorrectly rewritten here by the OP) holds, and how to prove it.

Comment: @ClementC. : I have added the statement at the end summarizing what I did. This should address your concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Regards..Sergio. One of ways to see the proof is by understanding the way the exact general solution is achieved. This will also make you understand more about the PDE.

One other way is to integrate the series. By writing the convergence : 
$$     \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{n \pi } \sin \left(\frac{n \pi x}{L} \right)  = c $$ where $c$ is the convergence value.
After this you should first integrate the sine series :

$$ \int \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n \pi } \sin \left(\frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) dx =
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} - \left(  \frac{L}{(n \pi)^2 } \right) \cos \left( \frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) = c L $$
Along the interval $ 0<x<L $. You will get the form below :

$$  \left(  \frac{2L}{( \pi)^2 } \right)  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k+1)^2} = cL $$

From there the series below will be useful :

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi}{6} $$

To find the value of :

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k + 1)^2}  $$

to find the value $c$. But i found that the value is different from what you post.

Hope this would be useful.

Comment: Read the comments -- the key is that the summation is over odd indices, $$\sum_{n \text{ odd}}$$ not $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty.$$ Your answer is not addressing the question/issue at all.

Comment: Regards @ClementC . Yes, by integration the summation of odd indices will appear. But the value is determined by subtracting the series of all indices by the even indices.

Comment: True -- but my point is that the OP's question is literally 
*My question is, how can I proof (sic) that $$\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}=1$$*

and your answer does not address that (e.g., by mentioning that it cannot be proven, as it is false; but holds when the summation is restricted to the odd indices, in which case [Did's comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2203988/convergence-of-sine-series#comment4534659_2203988) provides a derivation)

Comment: @ClementC Yes the convergence can be proven , but i prefer to give directions so that Sergio could perform the full proof himself.

Comment: But again -- then **first tell him the result he wanted to prove is wrong.** Otherwise, even with a correct derivation, he will be confused as to why he doesn't get what he expected.